# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near 'Reference'

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, syntax-error, sql-server-2014-express

I'm sure I'm missing something here, and could use a hand. The error message I'm getting is in the title.

I've got a column called `Agent Reference` with results as 80008_23456 etc etc, the first part is the same (80008) for every row with only the information after the '_' being different, I need to split the data so that I can join it to another table using the unique id. Hence the *case when* statement below, but I'm getting the error above and need some fresh eyes.

```
select 
    case when CHARINDEX('_',Agent Reference)>0 
         then SUBSTRING(Agent Reference,1,CHARINDEX('_', Agent Reference)-1) 
         else Agent Reference end, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',Agent Reference)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(Agent Reference,CHARINDEX('_',Agent Reference)+1,len(Agent Reference))  
         ELSE NULL END as Web_ID
from [Copy of RM_property_performance_report_export-TABLE];
go
```

Comment: Agent Reference - should be without spacing as AgentReference.

Comment: all sorted now with the parantheses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces aren't allowed in object names. If you want to to use a name like "Agent Reference" you should escape it by surrounding it in square brackets: `[Agent Reference]`.

Comment: Or if you want to use standard compliant SQL, use double quotes `"Agent Reference" `